# How to force specific AVInputFormat in code (FFMPEG)?

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, android-ndk, video-streaming

++Plaease understand that maybe some words or sentences could not be correct English.++

I'm novice programmer and developing a video player app for Android which can play 5ch .avi video from http. It based on ffplay.c in FFMPEG libarary.

Currently I have 2 problems for this below. It has occured only in android devices.

---

1) Too much time taken for detecting format.

- opening and finding stream info takes more than a minute when I trying to open 5ch video source whereas normal .mp4 (h264) source open almost immediately.

2) Demuxing is too slow when it comes to large size video.

- If the resolution of video getting larger, then displaying frame rate getting slower even though there are enough memory, network and CPU resources physically.

To resolve my problem, I tried to force the format and decoders but I couldn't found some information for specifying the input source in code level.
The [official doc site](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html) only refers to a sentence about those parameters like "If non-NULL, this parameter forces a specific input format. Otherwise the format is autodetected.". So I don't have any clues how to set the number of streams, decoders, decoders' private options, and etc. (And also which parameters should I manage.) If someone knows how to set the options(like AVDictionary), and pass to the av functions, please let me know an exmple. The source contains 2 video streams, 1 audio stream, and 2 more extra streams (for custom data like gps). The stream information of video is below. I printed it manually, and these are auto-detected information.

```
    ---------- File format information ----------
flags=2097152
video_codec_id=0 (NONE)
audio_codec_id=0 (NONE)
ctx_flags=0
data_codec_id=0 (NONE)
format_whitelist=(null)
iformat=0xa19d0d2c
---------- Stream information ----------
stream 1 of 5:
----- common ----------
bit_rate: 11383235
bits_per_coded_sample: 24
bits_per_raw_sample: 0
codec_id: 0x1C (H264)
codec_tag: 875967048
extradata_size: 0
level: -99
profile: -99
sample_rate: 0
----- Video Stream ----------
chroma_location: 0
color_primaries: 2
color_space: 2
color_trc: 2
field_order: 0
format: -1 (NONE)
height: 1080
width: 1920
sample_aspect_ratio.den: 1
sample_aspect_ratio.num: 0
video_delay: 0
----------------------------------------
stream 2 of 5:
----- common ----------
bit_rate: 6185438
bits_per_coded_sample: 24
bits_per_raw_sample: 0
codec_id: 0x1C (H264)
codec_tag: 875967048
extradata_size: 0
level: -99
profile: -99
sample_rate: 0
----- Video Stream ----------
chroma_location: 0
color_primaries: 2
color_space: 2
color_trc: 2
field_order: 0
format: -1 (NONE)
height: 720
width: 1280
sample_aspect_ratio.den: 1
sample_aspect_ratio.num: 0
video_delay: 0
----------------------------------------
stream 3 of 5:
----- common ----------
bit_rate: 352800
bits_per_coded_sample: 16
bits_per_raw_sample: 0
codec_id: 0x10000 (PCM_S16LE)
codec_tag: 1
extradata_size: 0
level: -99
profile: -99
sample_rate: 22050
----- Audio Stream ----------
block_align: 2
channels: 1
channel_layout: 0
color_range: 0
frame_size: 0
initial_padding: 0
seek_preroll: 0
trailing_padding: 0
----------------------------------------
stream 4 of 5:
----- common ----------
bit_rate: 15625
bits_per_coded_sample: 0
bits_per_raw_sample: 0
codec_id: 0x0 (NONE)
codec_tag: 0
extradata_size: 0
level: -99
profile: -99
sample_rate: 0
----- Subtitle Stream ----------
----------------------------------------
stream 5 of 5:
----- common ----------
bit_rate: 33862
bits_per_coded_sample: 0
bits_per_raw_sample: 0
codec_id: 0x0 (NONE)
codec_tag: 0
extradata_size: 0
level: -99
profile: -99
sample_rate: 0
----- Subtitle Stream ----------
```

Comment: since you have two problems, please consider opening a new question and editing this one.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you for your comment. But I guess those two problems are may derived from same cause (input format setting). So I organized it one question.